# Staking EOS for bandwidth

Tags: staking

How does one go about staking and unstaking their EOS? What if a user has more than one dApp - is it necessary to stake on a dApp basis? And if that’s true, resources used are computed on a dApp basis rather than for a  high level account as a whole?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically users and dApps are synonymous as far a resource allocation is concerned, similar to Ethereum, where it doesn't matter if the address is a contract or a person, as long as it pays for it's gas.

In this video Dan explains the process for resource allocation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6CTRdx6NVE

Essentially, bandwidth and CPU are staked for 3 days using a staking contract that will be [provided by block.one](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/cd0b147910af4e84dd079c934dbf9765dae75cd7/contracts/eosio.system) (for both smart contracts and users), and RAM is allocated and paid for in real-time (during this process either the sender or receiver can be charged for this).

Comment: Thanks. Viewed the video. I still wonder if you can have a hierarchy of accounts, and stake the high-level or, optionally, stake each individual (or both).

Comment: The beauty of this solution is any of the above is possible.