# Explain account parameters

Tags: accounts

[image]

I was going through the output of cleos get account myacc . I am finding it difficult to distinguish between the parameters of the output like memory, net bandwidth and cpu bandwidth. I know that i have to stake eos for computation , bandwidth and ram and that bandwidth is dependent on congestion so a bit variable and ram is fixed and can be purchased an dsold at the market price. Which is exactly what ?

As far as i interpret correct if i am wrong

1. memory is the space used by the persistent data structures like multi_index to store data .. if it is is it free or should be purchased by staking eos.
2. net bandwidth is the RAM . It is used for maintainence of state of the system which say for instance "cleos get actions myacc" uses to list all actions of the acc.It is fixed for the amount you have purchased from market price from eos.
3. cpu bandwidth is the flexible bandwidth accomplished by staking eos. It is used to limit the no of transactions you can perform kind of rate limiting such that you have to wait if you exceed the rate limit.

Comment: please replace the image with the copy of your terminal text, it helps the community to search for it

Comment: this the snapshot from the terminal with the command being "cleos get account myacc " . Is there something else i need to provide?

Answer (score 5):

- NET bandwidth is the amount of space in the blockchain log consumed.
- RAM is the amount of space in multi-index containers
- CPU is the wall-clock time consumed as measured by the producers when the execute your transaction.

Comment: Can you explain what type of data is stored in blockchain log?

Answer (score 0):

In my answer here:

[Staking EOS for bandwidth](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/385/staking-eos-for-bandwidth/398#398)

there is a video of Dan discussing the details of the staking in detail.  He answers all the questions you have here.